# Power Pivot error on opening a single file

Tags: powerpivot

I have a file that someone else send to me. He is able to open the Power Pivot model on his computer, but the same file fails to open on my computer. I also tried on other computers, and it is not working.

I am able to open other Power Pivot file, but not this one.

We are using the same version of Excel (2010) and Power Pivot (SQL 2012 SP2).

I always get this error:
[image]

Has anyone any recommendation?

Comment: Did you try uninstalling and reinstalling Power Pivot as it suggests?

Comment: Yes, tried that and didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a issue of vertipaq, did you have access engine install or vertipaq, if access engine try to uninstall it and install vertipaq, disable and enable the power pivot addin and try once.